# Declaring per-user (roaming user) configuration settings for a plugin DLL?

Tags: c#, windows, plugins, configuration, app-config

How can I setup support for per (roaming) user configuration settings for a particular plugin .DLL loaded from another application?

I have a .DLL that is loaded as add-in/plugin from another application, and want to persist configuration settings particular for this one independently of the main application that loads it, based on machine, .dll (=executable), roaming user or user profile.

I have found the `System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap` class that looks likely to provide what I need, but I can't figure out how to setup the right paths specific for my (**plugin**) application.

What code I have so far is:

```
public class MyConfigurationSettings : ConfigurationSection
{
    public static MyConfigurationSettings GetSection (ConfigurationUserLevel ConfigLevel) 
    {
        string configFile = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyConfigurationSettings)).Location + ".config";
        ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFile;
        configFileMap.LocalUserConfigFilename = <localUserConfigFile>; // ??? What filename to place here and how to get it based on the current environment ???
        configFileMap.RoamingUserConfigFilename = <roamingUserConfigFile>; // ???;

        System.Configuration.Configuration Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigLevel);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me into the right direction? The available documentation and search results are too confusing or insufficient for me to get this right. Sorry , if this seems to be a silly question, but my C# (.NET) skills are going to get rusty after 4+ years not using it for earning daily bread.

I also believe it's not primarily an issue about configuration settings management, but how to get paths for installation specific application instance configurations.

Comment: I have still left the [tag:c#] tag, to ensure that this question will get some attention at all, even if it's not relevant ...

Comment: Have you [read](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/08/03/xml-configuration-for-net-applications.aspx)?

Comment: @abatishchev No, didn't find this yet. Thank's it seems to be a promising resource. But doesn't it still state the plugin's configuration will be stored using the main application path's? I'll experiment with this ...

Comment: See my answer and links in it's end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `RoamingUserConfigFilename = RoamingName.config` and put it under Roaming Profile:

```
%AppData%\[AppName]\[Vendor]\[CodedPath]\[Version]\RoamingName.config
```

Also you set `LocalUserConfigFilename  = LocalName.config` and put it under Local Profile:

```
%LocalAppData%\[AppName]\[Vendor]\[CodedPath]\[Version]\LocalName.config
```

Now calling

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
    exeMap,
    ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
```

config will be read in the following order:

[image]

Source on [MSDN blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pedram/2007/08/03/xml-configuration-for-net-applications/).

For samples search for `User.config` under `c:\Users\[User]\AppData`. Also see [CP article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19675/Cracking-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration).

**Code Sample:**

```
public static MyConfigurationSettings GetSection (ConfigurationUserLevel ConfigLevel) 
{
    try
    {
        string appDataPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string localDataPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap exeMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        exeMap.ExeConfigFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDataPath, @"MyCompany\MyPlugin\Default.config");
        exeMap.RoamingUserConfigFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDataPath, @"MyCompany\MyPlugin\Roaming.config");
        exeMap.LocalUserConfigFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(localDataPath, @"MyCompany\MyPlugin\Local.config");

        System.Configuration.Configuration Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(exeMap,ConfigLevel);

        return (MyConfigurationSettings)Config.GetSection("MyConfigurationSettings");

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // ...
    }
    return null; // or throw an appropriate exception
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this well done answer, I'm convinced it will help others looking up the same problem. Another look to the links you provided got me to the right path. I'll add an updated code sample that works well for me.

Answer (score -2):

Generally load the configuration from the special folder where you put it in and put it into one of the roaming (i.e. non local) locations. The OS handles the rest as per roaming specifications.

The usage of ConfigSections is totally irrelevant unless there is a very very special need to use the config file for that. In any .NET project I have seen in the last 10 years this file was never used for user specific settings.

Comment: I have no 'special folder' where I'm putting my configuration in. So may be my question should be _'what are special folders, and how to use them?'_

Comment: And I definitely **need** per user specific settings for my purpose (may be 'roaming' can be ignored, since these are less spacific anyway AFAIK) ...

Comment: I bit less snobistic attitude and pointing to [Environment.SpecialFolders / ApplicationData, CommonApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) would have been sufficient, thanks ...

Comment: @g-makulik I have zero tolerance for people blaming the language ("c#" tag for their failure to read the documentation.

Comment: I've added [tag:.NET] tag meanwhile, and what relevance is C# without using .NET (windoze) at all. But I can understand your attitude insofar, that I'm also quite intolerant about people asking [tag:c++] questions while meaning 'C++ under windows using Visual Studio 2012' ... BTW I didn't _'blame'_ anything ...